# jQuery: how to return all elements that has been .data("tag","tagged")?

Tags: jquery

```
$('*').data('tag', "tagged");
```

`$('li[tag=tagged]').length` returns zero...

Comment: It would help if you could post a sample of the HTML you are running against...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('*').data('tag', "tagged");

$('li').each(
    function()
    {
        if( $(this).data('tag') === "tagged" )
        {
            //do something taggy ...like increment a count
        }
    }
);
```

Or, for something reuseable:

```
function getTaggedInJquery( jQueryObj )
{
    var total = 0;
    jQueryObj.each(
        function()
        {
            if( $(this).data('tag') === "tagged" )
                total++;
        }
    );
    return total;
}

alert( getTaggedInJquery( $('li') ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the `data(..)` method doesn't really set/append/create anything on the element you use it on.

It uses an internal dictionary object to hold the values and matches them via a uniquely generated id.

The solution proposed by Kevin Peno works but can get **very** costly very quick if you don't choose your selectors wisely.

Check http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js around line 1271++-

Comment: I agree. But anything gets costly if you're using selectors like "*". If it were me, I'd add attributes, and filter by that, rather than dealing with data for this.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you're using matches attributes on the HTML element, not jQuery `data` items.

AFAIK, jQuery has no built-in selector that matches `data` items.

You can either write your own selector or set your own attributes on the elements themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
var taggedElements = $.grep($('li').get(), function(n, i){
    return ($(n).data('tag') == 'tagged');
});
```